# Place values above line graph dots

Tags: chart.js

I feel this should be a very simple parameter but I have looked across a large number of SO questions and simply not found it (and the docs).

I have a line graph and would like to place the value of the point permanently above it like so:

[image]

I'm not worried about the shading (although if its possible great) but is there a parameter I can enable to place the values above? I don't want them to hover because I'm actually converting the graph to an image.

Comment: `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` library provides what you're looking for: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels

Comment: Super - thanks for the pointer. Obviously isn't something chart.js does by default then.